# Symfony: how to relation a Entity field to several Entities

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

My database diagram corresponds to:

[image]

Each table has his own Symfony Entity class. My app view shows:

[image]

I need to associate a Discount Entity to multiple entities: Sneaker, Tshirt, Trouser or even more entities.

**First solution:**

Create N:N tables between discounts and the others. The problem is that I could need create new tables to apply discount and then I would have to create more N:N tables. So I discard this solution.

**Second solution:**

Create a `generic` table with `to_entity` and `to_entity_id` fields that let me map discount to `to_entity` entity destination (Sneaker, Tshirt, Trouser or other):

[image]

How can I implement second solution in Symfony ? Or is there another solution possible ?

Thanks.

Comment: For your second solution you might want to take a look at doctrine inheritance. http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html Basically use a Superclass like `Article` which is extended by your different types and define whichever relation your discount needs to the superclass instead.

Answer (score 0):

Polymorphism with Doctrine is not easy at all.

1. Try to solve it through [mapped superclasses and/or inheritance](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html). Your first solution could be simplified by using single-table inheritance. You should change the discriminator map for every new "discountable" entity.
2. Investigate on [Dynamic mapping](https://www.theodo.fr/blog/2013/11/dynamic-mapping-in-doctrine-and-symfony-how-to-extend-entities/) through [loadClassMetadata](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#load-classmetadata-event) event. You can create OneToMany relationships for every entity implementing a custom interface (i.e. DiscountableInterface).